# Keep Xamarin Android app/game running when locked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on my very first Xamarin app. It's a GPS-based game, with 1 team searching for a certain person which is also using the app. The person "running" sends a GPS location every "X" minutes. As you guys understand this game has to work even when the "running" person has locked his/her phone or has put it in their pocket.

Is it possible to keep this app running under these conditions? Can i keep using location services, timers and database connections? I've searched for this on the internet already, and people where saying this was impossible due to security reasons, but couldn't find any proper answer for this specific question.

Can somebody please tell me if this is possible and how to start with it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The Activity will be paused when the screen is locked, but you may be able to accomplish this with a Service.

Comment: Should I run the whole game as a service or only when the device is locked?

Comment: You should run the tasks that would need to occur in the background as a service, ie the gps updates, then apply the changes when the activity wakes up.

Comment: At the very least you should do some study on [Xamarin Android Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/). I wouldn't classify this problem as trivial, so it's going to take some doing to get a solution that is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @JonathonChase But do I have full functionality when running as a serice, like database connections? What do you mean with applying changes, updating GUI? Or sending data to the database?

Comment: I will take a look at that link first.

Comment: @JonathonChase In my case, do you recommend a Bound or a IntentService?

Answer (score 1):

The heavyweight solution would be a `Service`. If you wanted updates at intervals of seconds, this might be the best solution. But since you said minutes, it's probably better to use an [alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). This will fire more or less on schedule even if the framework decides to kill your app while it's in the background. (See the section of the docs about precision.)

[Xamarin `AlarmManager`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.AlarmManager/)

The possible drawback of an alarm is that even if GPS is already up and running on the device, it may take a couple seconds after the alarm fires to receive a location update. Since you mentioned that the user can decrease the interval to seconds, you might want to try both solutions and see which works best. One may be clearly better for your application, or there may be a trade off between reliability and battery usage.

Comment: It's also possible to send update like every 10-15 seconds, that depends on the settings selected by the user.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying both options. I think i'll try a service first. As I read on a MSDN page there are 4 types of services. 2 which almost are guaranteed to work in all situations; Bound- and Intentservices. Which one do you recommend me if I'll give this a go?

Comment: @Basvo I don't know if Xamarin exposes this, but you might want to look into foreground vs. background services. A foreground service is the least likely to be killed when the app is in the background.